# Call to Odata service via service reference returns null

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, odata, wcf-data-services

I'm  using a working sample Odata service `http://services.odata.org/v3/(S(ttgz0nndpwaj2eahro3jq0xt))/odata/odata.svc/`

**I did the following steps:**
create console application -> add service reference -> put the URL -> go -> then I saw the service with all the entities *(like product suppliers etc)* -> press OK and put the following code. Assuming I want to get the product data, how should I do that?

I use the following code to get the data, but without success, any idea ? *(I guess I should call on the service proxy that was generated but I'm not sure how...)*

One additional question : suppose the service has basic authentication and I need to provide a username and a password, how should I do that?

```
OdataService.Product Client = new OdataService.Product();



// Query the weather information.
var Output = from ThisData
             in Client.Products
             select ThisData;

Console.WriteLine(Output.ToString());
Console.ReadLine();
```

This is the URL `http://services.odata.org/v3/(S(ttgz0nndpwaj2eahro3jq0xt))/odata/odata.svc/Products`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to create an instance of the Product rather than an instance of the service proxy. You can create an instance of OdataService and you have to pass in the Url of the service. This should work:

```
var service = new OdataService(new Uri("http://services.odata.org/v3/(S(ttgz0nndpwaj2eahro3jq0xt))/odata/odata.svc"));
service.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials; // Set your credentials here if you need to
var products = service.Products.ToList(); // Gives a list of products
```

Comment: Error 1 'CallToOdataService.OdataService' is a 'namespace' but is used like a 'type' 
Error 2 The name 'CredentialCache' does not exist in the current context

Comment: I don't know what you have called your Service Reference when you imported it, use the Object Browser to look in the OdataService namespace to find the class which derives from DataServiceContext, that's what you need to create by passing the Url in.

Comment: And CredentialCache can be found in the System.Net namespace (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.credentialcache(v=vs.110).aspx). You don't need to set the Credentials for the service you posted, that was just in case you need to set basic authentication as you mentioned.